# need help in solving selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am using PyCharm and I was following a YouTube tutorial. After copying their method I'm not getting the desired results.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")

InstaBot()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prxthm/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    InstaBot()
  File "/Users/prxthm/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bot.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: You have to add a full path till chromedriver.exe. I believe you just went till the folder and forgot to append the file name in the last.

Comment: OK - so in your latest code, there's no path defined to the chromedriver.exe location. Did you remove that? - and what's the error when you run the code?

Comment: I have updated the error, and how do I define the path to the chromedriver.exe

Comment: you define the path as mentioned in the answer below... `browser = webdriver.Chrome('/full/path/to/your/exe/chromedriver.exe')`   ... when you run `pip show selenium` what's the output? and finally, what's your version of chromedriver, does it match your intsalled chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Give the path where your chromedriver is saved in this format, I have enetered the path where I have saved my webdriver.exe file :

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\dt\\workspace_python\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")`

Try using two `\\`

Comment: How did I forget to mention I'm using a mac, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

Make sure your path is the .exe for chromedriver - probably one of these:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/prxthm/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
#or
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/prxthm/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
```

If these don't work, can you please enure you share your error. Typically the error is the best clue on how to solve a problem.

As well as tutorials, it's also good to read the supporting documentation.

- For more information on installing selenium for python see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)
- For more information on getting started see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: okay so I'm having a new error from your code i.e SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Which line? Eol is end of line. Have you tried to investigate why the error occurs?

Comment: There was a rogue apostrophe at the end of the second line. I've updated the code. Was that it?

Comment: it is again saying 'function' has no attribute 'chrome'

Comment: You've definitely installed selenium via pip, and you've definitely got the right path to the chromedriver exe? .... How are you executing your script?

Comment: Can you please update your post to have the full code you're using now and share the full error text?

Comment: yes, I have definitely installed selenium via pip I may be wrong on the path side I just don't know how and I have updated my post. Thank you btw for sticking around.